# Ionic 2 Validating username at signup

Tags: validation, angular, ionic2, custom-validators

I'm new to Ionic/Angular 2..

Try to use custom validators to validate the username but at server but i´m stack into this problem...

> Property 'getUserByLogin' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   UserValidator'.

I have an sigunp.html page ...

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
        <ion-title>{{ "SIGNUP" | translate }}</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="login-page">

    <div class="logo">
        <img src="assets/img/appicon.svg" alt="Ionic Logo">
    </div>

    <ion-card>
        <p ion-text>Teste</p>
        <ion-card-content *ngFor="let user of users">
        <h1>{{user.nome}}</h1>
        <p>{{user.password}}</p>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

    <form [formGroup]="signupForm" (ngSubmit)="postSignupForm()" >
        <ion-list no-lines>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>{{ "USER_NAME" | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-input  type="text" formControlName="login" clearInput></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item  text-wrap *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.login.valid && (signupForm.controls.login.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p ion-text color="danger">{{ "INVALID_USER_NAME" | translate }}</p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item *ngIf="signupForm.controls.login.pending">
                <p ion-text color="danger">{{ "VALIDATION_IN_PROGRESS" | translate }}</p>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.login.valid && !signupForm.controls.login.pending && (signupForm.controls.login.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p ion-text color="danger">{{ "USER_NAME_IN_USE" | translate }}</p>
            </ion-item>


            <ion-item>
                <ion-label floating>{{ "PASSWORD" | translate }}</ion-label>
                <ion-input  type="password" formControlName="password" clearInput></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item  text-wrap *ngIf="!signupForm.controls.password.valid && (signupForm.controls.password.dirty || submitAttempt)">
                <p ion-text color="danger">{{ "INVALID_PASSWORD" | translate }}</p>
            </ion-item>

            <ion-item>
                <ion-buttons end>
                    <ion-row responsive-sm>
                        <ion-col>
                            <button [disabled]="signupForm.invalid" type="submit" ion-button icon-left block>
                                <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
                                <label>{{ "CREATE" | translate }}</label>
                            </button>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col>
                            <button (click)="onFacebook(signupForm)" ion-button icon-left block>
                                <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                                <label>{{ "FACEBOOK" | translate }}</label>
                            </button>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
             </ion-buttons>
             </ion-item>


        </ion-list>
    </form>

</ion-content>
```

And a signup.ts with

```
import { Component }              from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgForm }                 from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController }          from 'ionic-angular';
import { TabsPage }               from '../tabs/tabs';

import { UserData }      from '../../providers/user-data';
import { UserProvider }  from '../../providers/user-provider';
import { UserValidator } from '../../validators/user-validator';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-user',
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage {

  signupForm : any = {};
  users :any [];
  id : number = 0;

  signup: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};
  submitted = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public formBuilder : FormBuilder, public userData: UserData, public userService : UserProvider ) {

    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      login : ['', Validators.compose( [ Validators.minLength(6)
                                       , Validators.required
                                       , Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*') ] )
                                       , UserValidator.checkUsername 
              ],
      password : ['', Validators.compose( [ Validators.minLength(6)
                                          , Validators.required 
                                          ] ) 
                 ]
    });

  }

  getAllUsers() {
    return this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(
      data=>this.users=data,
      err=>console.log(err)

    )
  }

  getUser( id : number ) {
    return this.userService.getUser( id ).subscribe(
      data=>this.users=data,
      err=>console.log(err)

    )
  }

  getUserByLogin( login : string  ) {
    return this.userService.getUserByLogin( login ).subscribe(
      data=>this.users=data,
      err=>console.log(err)

    )
  }

  postSignupForm (){
    console.log( this.signupForm.value );
  }

  onSignup(form: NgForm) {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (form.valid) {
      this.userData.signup(this.signup.username);
      this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
    }
  }

  onFacebook(form: NgForm) {

    this.getUser(2);

    console.log( form.value );   
  }


}
```

Where i call an UserValidator.checkUsername that is created at...

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { UserProvider }  from '../providers/user-provider';

export class UserValidator {

    wsreturn : any = [];

    constructor( public userService : UserProvider ) {
    }

    getUserByLogin( login : string  ) {
        return this.userService.getUserByLogin( login ).subscribe(
          data=>this.wsreturn=data,
          err=>console.log(err)

        )
      };


    static checkUsername(control: FormControl): any {

    return new Promise(resolve => {

        //console.log ( '------->' ); console.log ( control.value );

      this.getUserByLogin( control.value ); ///  I NEED HELP!


      // Fake a slow response from server
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(control.value.toLowerCase() === "luciano"){

          resolve({
            "username taken": true
          });

        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      }, 2000);

    });
  }

}
```

My user-privider is this one...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { GlobalProvider }  from '../providers/global-provider';

@Injectable()
export class UserProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http, public global: GlobalProvider) {

  }

    getAllUsers() {
        return this.http.get(this.global.serverAdress + '/usuario', { headers: this.global.headers } ).map(res=>res.json())
    }

    getUser( id : number ) {
        return this.http.get(this.global.serverAdress + '/usuario/'+ id, { headers: this.global.headers } ).map(res=>res.json())
    }

    getUserByLogin( login : string ) {
        return this.http.get(this.global.serverAdress + '/usuario/porlogin/'+ login, { headers: this.global.headers } ).map(res=>res.json())
    }

    postUser( id : number ) {
        return this.http.get(this.global.serverAdress + '/usuario/'+ id, { headers: this.global.headers } ).map(res=>res.json())
    }
}
```

Comment: any particular reason for static ?

Comment: Nops, this was part of another sample. @suraj

Comment: Have you tried injecting the Uservalidator class? also generally custom validators for angular 2 are done this way: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation

Answer (score 0):

you can not call `instance` method in `static` method with `this` keyword. create directive instead

```
import { Directive, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALIDATORS, FormControl, Validator } from '@angular/forms';


@Directive({
  selector: '[checkUsername][ngModel],[checkUsername][formControl]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckUsernameValidator), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class CheckUsernameValidator implements Validator {


  constructor(public userService: UserProvider) {
  }

  getUserByLogin(login : string) {
    return this.userService.getUserByLogin(login);
  };

  validate(c: FormControl) {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // 

      this.getUserByLogin( control.value ).subscribe(
        data => {
          if(control.value.toLowerCase() === "luciano"){

            resolve({
              "username taken": true
            });

          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err);
          resolve(null);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

in your html:

```
<ion-input  type="text" formControlName="login" checkUsername clearInput></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I move checkUsername to signup.ts with and made some changes to "bind(this)"... its working as i want but i´m still reading more about "creating directives"...

thanks @tiep-phan and @suraj.

....

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public formBuilder : FormBuilder, public userData: UserData, public userService : UserProvider ) {

    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      login : ['', Validators.compose( [ Validators.minLength(6)
                                       , Validators.required
                                       , Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z]*') ] )
                                       , this.checkUsername.bind(this)
              ],
      password : ['', Validators.compose( [ Validators.minLength(6)
                                          , Validators.required 
                                          ] ) 
                 ]
    });

  }

  checkUsername(control: FormControl): any {

   return new Promise( resolve => {

      this.userService.getUserByLogin( control.value ).subscribe(
          data=>{ 
          // console.log('Sucesso:');  console.log(data[0]);
          if ( typeof data[0] !== "undefined") {
            if ( typeof data[0].login === "undefined") {
              resolve(null);
            } else {
              // username encontrado no banco de dados
              resolve( { "INVALID_USER_NAME": true } );
            }
          } else {
             resolve(null);
            }
          },
          err=>{ console.log('Erro:'); console.log(err); }
        )
    });
  }
```

....